# Can we reopen this morphology question?

Tags: support, reopen

The following morphology question is useful and interesting. The question isn't excellently framed. The OP, of course, would find it difficult to frame in the first place, unless they knew words like *suffix, affix* and so forth. It is difficult to pinpoint what the problem is. However, it brings up an important point about English grammar, English morphology in particular, which is useful for learners:

[Is the word 'restrictionable' correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71389/is-the-word-restrictionable-correct?noredirect=1#comment136568_71389)

This is a good grammar question and is useful for learners. One might think that this is a "go and look in a dictionary" type question. Or, perhaps, a "Google it and see if you get any examples" type question. However, it isn't, because it's not about word meaning. It is a grammar question. Many affixes in English can be used productively to make words that no-one has ever said before, and which have never appeared in a dictionary before. The problem with the OP's word, is that it isn't grammatical. It's badly formed, because the root being used is a noun not a verb. (It's actually a bit more complicated than this, but you'd need to ask an expert like Snailboat, for example, for the further particulars).

Of course, the OP can't see exactly what they've done wrong or why it's wrong - if they knew that they would be able to answer the question!

I think that this question is useful for learners. Any chance of a reopen vote or two from the gentle readers here?

Comment: That question is now reopened. While I don't believe the original question was as deep as you presume it to be, I heartily thank you and @Nihilist for the effort. Case closed I guess.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M No, it wasn't deep. It was a basic student grammar problem that any teacher or expert here to help learners should be able to recognise and help with. The questions here aren't meant to be entertainment for long-term members who aren't interested in specific types of question and find them boring. Neither are the guidelines for good questions meant to bar users from asking good questions when they only have an intuitive understanding of their problem. They're there to stop unproductive questions. ...

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M ... For anybody claiming to be an expert able to help learners, which is what we're meant to be as closers, answerers and so forth, this was an important question, as you'll appreciate.

Comment: I'm voting to close/delete this question because it is a request to re-open a question that has now been re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

This question is now reopened. C'est la vie.